# Application-descriptor.xml error while upgrading Worklight 6.0.0 to 6.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have a project connected to SVN and I try to upgrade it to 6.1
but I'm getting the following Error all the time.
I have tried importing the project with 6.1 studio, or opening it with 6.0.0 and then upgrading and I'm still getting the same error:

```
[2014-02-04 15:15:50] FWLST1022I: Starting to migrate the Assessor project from version 6.0.0 to version 6.1.0.0. 
[2014-02-04 15:15:50] FWLPL0025I: The Assessor project is being saved as C:\work\code\mobile\AssesoriPhone\Assessor\Assessor_2014_02_04_151550.backup.zip file. 

[2014-02-04 15:16:14] FWLPL0019E: Migrating the Assessor project from version 6.0.0 to version 6.1.0.0 has failed because this migration path is not supported: 
Failed reading application-descriptor.xml
```

and the icon of the project change to [image]

I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426

Answer (score 1):

This is known defect that has an open and active PMR about it.

As a workaround, you can delete the `.svn` files from the `apps` folder and the migration should then pass when importing the project.

Comment: But this way I will lose all my history of project

Comment: This is the workaround to enable you to migrate your project containing .svn files to Worklight 6.1. You may choose to use it and you may choose not to use it. If you are an IBM business partner or customer, you can open a PMR and wait for the fix to be available.

Comment: Maybe you can try to remove > migrate > re-add the .svn files from their locations; It's tedious, but maybe it'll work.